# Javascript NaN large integer error

Tags: javascript

So I was calculating last ten digit of the series :

1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^1000

But I keep getting NaN as a result.

Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var i, x, a, sum = 0; {
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      var a = Math.pow(i, i);
      sum += a;
    }
    var x = sum;
    var y = x % 10000000000;

  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to demontrate </p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Javascript numbers can hold values up to (2^31 - 1) and not more than that

Comment: @Suhas so how should I handle it.

Comment: @Somesh you can try using an external library for handling big integers, like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Infinity value - try the code below :

```
function myFunction() {

  var i, x, a, sum = 0; {
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      var a = Math.pow(i, i);
      if(a!=Infinity)sum += a;
    }
    var x = sum;
    var y = x % 10000000000;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks , this code worked without using any external library.

Comment: I don't feel this is correct. This is ignoring all values that are infinity (`a != infinity`), so basically it will stop adding values once JS Number starts overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Math.pow(1000, 1000)
```

Thats a very very huge number, (3000 zeros), so javascript can't handle it, thats why the above results in `Infinity`. And the modulo of an infinite number cannot be determined, therefore the result is Not A Number.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses 64-bit floating point numbers for everything. The max value of one of those is about 1.8 × 10^308, which is quite a bit smaller than your 1000^1000 value. As a consequence, since the number it's trying to calculate can't fit into a "number"-type variable, Javascript returns NaN and leaves it at that.

Comment: So how I should I get the result without NaN, is there any other method to display this result.

Comment: You'd probably want to see user2693928's solution below, and use a [BigNumber](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) that isn't constrained by byte limits.

Answer (score 0):

Number.MAX_VALUE is the maximum number available.

Otherwise you have to use some library for example: https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Big Ints (greater than (2^31 - 1) as @suhas explained) are not currently supported in JS, however there is [a TC39 draft](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) currently in stage 3 (candidate).

**Solution**

In the meantime, use a library [such as this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer).

Answer (score 0):

As @jonas-w correctly pointed out, your specific problem is trying to take the modulo of an infinite number. `infinity % anyNumber` yields NaN.

In addition, you need to understand that floating-point values use scientific notation. That means that for large numbers, all of your significant digits (53 for IEEE 754 double-precision, which is what JavaScript uses) are at the upper end of the value, yet your modulo is examining the lower end.

For example, 1.1×10^6 is 1,100,000, and 1.2×10^6 is 1,200,000. Getting the `% 100` is pointless, as both yield 0.

What are you trying to accomplish with this code?